XLOOKUP with flexible column and search criteria which is not unique




A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I




1




2023
2024

Column



2







2024



3
Bike A

Shop1

500
60





4
Bike B

Shop4

100
150

Selected Data
Result


5
Bike C

Shop3

800
200

150
Bike B


6
Bike D

Shop2

90
150

150
Bike D


7
Bike E

Shop1

45
790

790
Bike E


8
Bike F

Shop1

600
40

980
Bike G


9
Bike G

Shop4

900
980






In Range I5:I8 I want to select the corresponding value from Column A based on the number in Range H5:H8 and the column in Cell H2.
Currently, I am trying to use this VLOOKUP function:
=XLOOKUP(H6,$F$1:$F$9,$A$1:$A$9,NA(),0)

However, as you can see 

the Column F is fixed but it should be flexible based on the input in Cell H2 and 

if a number appears multiple times in Range H5:H8 (in this example 150) the formula only displays the first finding (in this example only Bike B) but it should display all findings.


How do I have to modify it to make it work?

Try using the following formula:


=FILTER(A3:A9,1-ISNA(XMATCH(CHOOSECOLS(E3:F9,XMATCH(H2,E1:F1)),H5:H8)))


Or,
=FILTER(A3:A9,1-ISNA(XMATCH(XLOOKUP(H2,E1:F1,E3:F9,""),H5:H8)))


Or,
=FILTER(A3:A9,COUNTIF(H5:H8,XLOOKUP(H2,E1:F1,E3:F9,"")))



Thanks for the answer. It works in the very specific example above. However, when I change the order of the values in H5:H8 to for example 980,790,150,150 the order of the result stays as in your screenshot. Is it possible to also adjust the order of the result accordingly to the values in H5:H8?

@Michi sorry I am not going to answer that, because that was not part of the question. Since you have commented here, I will also comment the same here, hope it helps, here is what you can do: =IFERROR(SORTBY(FILTER(A3:A9,COUNTIF(H5:H8,XLOOKUP(H2,E1:F1,E3:F9,"")),""),H5:H8),"")

Also, saying it works in the very specific example, if all the conditions are met the above formulas definitely should work. No where in the post it was mentioned that the ordering will be whimsical or random! And this is quite common using XLOOKUP() one cannot return multiple records for a unique lookup value. Yes it can be done not that, but in a complicated way as well with helpers, but returning for multiple records there are dedicated functions. like FILTER() or INDEX()+AGGREGATE()/SMALL() for older versions

I opened a new question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78677150/display-filter-results-in-the-same-order-as-the-values-in-the-criteria-range

@Michi You opened and I have posted answer !!
