Display FILTER results in the same order as the values in the criteria range




A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I




1




2023
2024

Column



2







2024



3
Bike A

Shop1

500
60





4
Bike B

Shop4

100
150

Selected Data
Result


5
Bike C

Shop3

800
200

980
Bike G


6
Bike D

Shop2

90
150

60
Bike A


7
Bike E

Shop1

45
790

150
Bike B


8
Bike F

Shop1

600
40

150
Bike D


9
Bike G

Shop4

900
980






In Range I5:I8 I want to select the corresponding value from Column A based on the number in Range H5:H8 and the column in Cell H2.
With reference to the answer in this question I implemented this formula:
=IFERROR(SORTBY(FILTER(A3:A9,COUNTIF(H5:H8,XLOOKUP(H2,E1:F1,E3:F9,"")),""),H5:H8),"")

With this formula the result looks like this:
Bike D
Bike G
Bike B
Bike A

This is almost correct since it includes all the values that I am searching for. 
However, I would like to have them in the same order as the values in Range H5:H8.
How do I need to modify the formula to make it work?

Here is one way of achieving the desired outcome:


=LET(
     α, H5:H8,
     δ, XLOOKUP(H2,E1:F1,E3:F9,""),
     φ, FILTER(HSTACK(A3:A9,δ),COUNTIF(α,δ)),
     SORTBY(TAKE(φ,,1), XMATCH(TAKE(φ,,-1),α)))


Or, Not sure which version of Excel you are using presently, so an alternative way.
=LET(
     α, H5:H8,
     δ, XLOOKUP(H2,E1:F1,E3:F9,""),
     Σ, FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},A3:A9,δ),1-ISNA(XMATCH(δ,α))),
     SORTBY(INDEX(Σ,,1),XMATCH(INDEX(Σ,,2),α)))


I realized there is a flaw in the above formulas if the duplicate values in the selected data are not consecutive then above will give FALSE Positives:


=LET(
     α, H5:H8,
     δ, XLOOKUP(H2,E1:F1,E3:F9,""),
     φ, FILTER(HSTACK(A3:A9,δ),COUNTIFS(α,δ,α,"<>")),
     SORTBY(TAKE(φ,,1),XMATCH(SEQUENCE(ROWS(φ)),
     XMATCH(α,TAKE(φ,,-1))+MAP(α,LAMBDA(ε,COUNTIF(ε:H5,ε)*(ε<>"")))-1)))


One more addition to the above formula(Please refer the screenshot it takes care of few things, hope the screenshot helps to understand, cant help with other ways needs LAMBDA() helpers here):


=LET(
     _Data, A3:F9,
     _Col, XLOOKUP(H2,A1:F1,_Data,""),
     _SelectedData, H5:H8,
     _Fx, LAMBDA(r,s, MAP(r,LAMBDA(c,COUNTIF(s:c,c)/10+c))),
     TOCOL(IF(_Fx(_Col,TAKE(_Col,1))=TOROW(_Fx(_SelectedData,
     TAKE(_SelectedData,1))),TAKE(_Data,,1),NA()),3,1))


Test Case:



@Mayukh Bhattacharya: Thanks for additional formulas. When I apply the third formula in your answer it only works if there are exactly four values given in the data range H5:H8. For example if I delete the last value (150) the formula returns #VALUE!. The very first formula which you posted does not have this issue.

@Michi yes, I know, but your query is also not clear here, this is because, i have to make some assumptions here. First assumptions : There can be duplicate values, Second assumptions : There may or may not be a duplicate value. Third Assumption: If one of the duplicate value is there then take only the first one. So lot of things which are not clear on the post, and also you dont reply very often. so i have to do guess work. You need to use the 4th formula. I had no choice but had to use LAMBDA() helper functions. as far i know you dont have access to those, isnt it?

@Michi can you confirm I am updating the third one. Looks its fixed! Please check Screenshot

My pick would be the SORTBY + XMATCH one.(though it is flawed)
